# ASP.NET : Category and subcategory in dropdownlist asp.net mvc 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu

```
I have a table with: 
 tbl_Category
  Id        |           Name            |       ParentID

  1                 Category 1                      0
  2                 Category 2                      0
  3                 Subcategory 11                  1
  4                 Subcategory 12                  1
  5                 Subcategory 21                  2
  6                 Subcategory 211                 5
  7                 Subcategory 22                  2
.........

How do I return it in a dropdownlist in the below format:

Category 1
--Subcategory 11
--Subcategory 12
--Subcatgory 13
Category 2
--Subcategory 21
----Subcategory 211
----Subcategory 212
--Subcategory 22
--Subcatgory 23
Category 3
--Subcategory 31
--Subcategory 32
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use html in your text so for example try:

```
Category1
&nbsp;Subcategory11
```

etc. This way the text will be indented to the right according to the category level

Comment: I need to get it in the database and display to view. How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

The `Html.DropDownListFor` helper method is capable of rendering the items in group. You just need to specify the `Group` property for each `SelectListItem`.

```
var group1 = new SelectListGroup {Name = "Category 1"};
var group2 = new SelectListGroup { Name = "Category 2" };

var options= new List<SelectListItem>
{
    new SelectListItem {Value = "1", Text = "Subcategory 11", Group = group1},
    new SelectListItem {Value = "2", Text = "Subcategory 12", Group = group1},
    new SelectListItem {Value = "3", Text = "Subcategory 21", Group = group2}
};
```

Usage of the helper method

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(s=>s.SomeProperty,options)
```

Or the `DropDownList` helper

```
@Html.DropDownList("MySelectName", options)
```

**Getting data ?**

If you are using Entity framework for your data access, you can execute this  code to get the grouped data in your action method.

```
var db = new YourDbContextHere();  // Replace your db context class here
var parentsDictionary = db.Categories 
                          .ToDictionary(d => d.Id, v => v.Name);

var groups = db.Categories.Select(x => x.Name)
        .Select(f => new SelectListGroup() { Name = f }).ToList();

var itemsWithParents = (from c in db.Categories
                        join p in db.Categories
                        on c.ParentId equals p.Id
                        select new { Id = c.Id, 
                                     Text = c.Name, 
                                     ParentId = c.ParentId }).ToList();

var groupedData = itemsWithParents
                   .Where(f => f.ParentId != 0)
                   .Select( x => new SelectListItem
                               {
                                 Value = x.Id.ToString(),
                                 Text = x.Text,
                                 Group = groups
                                        .First(a => 
                                                a.Name == parentsDictionary[x.ParentId])
                               }).ToList();
ViewBag.GroupedCategory= groupedData;
return View();
```

I am using ViewBag to transfer the data assuming you do not have a view model.

Now in your view, use the `DropDownList` helper method,

```
  @Html.DropDownList("SelectedCategory",ViewBag.GroupedCategoryas List<SelectListItem>)
```

Comment: I need to get in database, use Model, Controller, View display it.

Comment: I don't know what your data access technology is. So can't help there

Comment: I use asp.net mvc 5 . Model will get data from table tbl_Category and show  View

Comment: there are tons of ways to get data from the table. Are you using an ORM, using DataReader ?

Comment: I just tried the code i posted in the answer and it totally worked for me. See here http://imgur.com/a/ycszu  You must be doing something else